# Deleting from subquery

Tags: mysql

My query isn't working:

```
DELETE FROM (
     SELECT *
     FROM `chat`
     ORDER BY `message_id` ASC
     LIMIT 50
) AS deleted
```

Comment: why not , just delete first, and select after

Comment: Problem is in that query: DELETE FROM (SELECT * FROM `chat` ORDER BY `message_id` ASC LIMIT $NUM) AS deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql3 = "DELETE FROM chat ORDER BY message_id LIMIT ".$NUM;
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the subquery:

```
DELETE c FROM `chat` c
    ORDER BY `message_id` ASC
    LIMIT $NUM;
```

In MySQL, `DELETE` supports `order by` and `limit`.